# UICollectionViewCell With Dynamic Size Cell Spacing Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm Creating Custom UICollectionViewCell it's size automatically set from it's Content.

The Dynamic Size of cell is Working But In That It Have Extra Space.

**So I Want to remove extra Space Between Two Cell**

I'm also set UICollectionView DataSource and Delegate and Impalement It's Method But Still it is not Working

[image]

In One Row not fix their only 2 cell. It have 1, 2, or 3 cell it's depend on Text

CustomeCollectionViewCell.m

```
- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    CGSize size = self.lblText.intrinsicContentSize;
    size.width += 48;   // add padding Width that Given in Cell
    size.height += 32;  // add padding Height
    return size;
}
```

ViewController.m

```
@interface ViewController () <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
@property (strong, nonatomic) CustomeCollectionViewCell *tempCell;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *dataArr;
@end


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.dataArr = @[@"abcdef”,@"abcdef”,@"abcdef”,@"abcdef”,@"abcdef”];
    self.tempCell = (CustomeCollectionViewCell*) [[[UINib nibWithNibName:@“CustomeCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] firstObject];

    [self.collectionView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 8, 8)];
    [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomeCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomeCollectionViewCell"];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.dataArr.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomeCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomeCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.lblText.text = [self.dataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.tempCell.lblText.text = [self.dataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    return self.tempCell.intrinsicContentSize;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Dynamic Size of cell with following delegate method

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return CGSizeMake((self.view.frame.size.width - 15)/2, (self.view.frame.size.width - 15)/2);
}
```

Comment: In one Row not Fix 2 cell or Three it's Depend on Content